# Confusion on the definition of an indexed family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology

Ive recently been learning set theory and a bit of topology and im very confused on the definition of an indexed family.

Why do we say a family of sets instead of a collection of sets?
And why is the definition of an indexed family a function as such:

A family of elements  $S$ indexed by $I$ and denoted by $\{A_{i}|i\in I\}$ is a function $A:I\longrightarrow S$.
For example why do we say that an indexed family can be shown as a set $\{A_{i}|i\in I\}$  i thought that a family could have repetition so why can we express it as a set?.

I'm probably not being too clear and this is all surely trivial to you all but its very confusing to me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are several related posts on this topic, which on my browser appear on this very page under the heading "Related". Have you looked at any of them?

Comment: See whether the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3784585/about-the-definition-of-the-indexed-set-of-a-family?rq=1) helps.

Comment: The notation $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ for indexed families is indeed very unfortunate (and inconsistent with other standard notation!) and not everyone uses it.

Comment: Seconding @EricWofsey's comment: curly braces here to indicate a function is most unfortunate. It's basically *wrong*: the notation indicates a set comprehension – one that denotes, in this case, the range of the function $i \mapsto A_i$ with domain $I$, the things being indexed but not the indexing itself. More common notations for this function (indexed family) are $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(A_i \mid i \in I)$.